# Ubuntu 22.04 on guest VM through Virtualbox cannot access network

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox Version 6.1.34 r150636 (Qt5.6.2)
Ubuntu 22.04

VirtualBox Network is running on NAT network adaptor:
[image]

My enp0s3 port is dead and doesn't have IP address:
[image]

Cannot access the network:
[image]

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: enp0s8 assigned itself an ip fallback address.  This is often because it could not reach  a dhcp server

Answer (score 0):

I would first check VBox settings to make sure you have:

Setting > Advanced > Shared Clipboard: Bidirectional
Drag'n'Drop: Bidirectional

Settings > Network > Adapter 1 > Attached to: Bridged Adapter